# under linux, c function has crazy behaviour

Tags: c, function

I got a c function that has an incorrect behavior and I never seen something like this maybe someone could enlighten me about this complete mystery

so in test.c, the function is :

```
float wtf(int c)
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

in main.c

```
float a=wtf(0);
float b=wtf(2);
float c=wtf(3);
float d=wtf(4);
printf("%f %f %f %f\n",a,b,c,d);
```

and the result :

```
0.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000
```

now why is the parameter somehow output by the function that should output 0 ?

here is how I compile it under linux

```
cc -std=c99 -I"/usr/include/pd" -DPD -DVERSION='"0.0"' -fPIC -O6 -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer  -Wall -W -g -o "main.o" -c "main.c" -lpng -lbcm2835 -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-comment -lc
```

can someone help me out ?
regards

Comment: if it's true then it's probably a compiler bug. i think it's better for you to provide a complete example for us easy to test your code. the most important thing is, what's your gcc version?

Comment: Does that also happen if you put all the code in a single file and use a trimmed-down command-line (`cc -std=c99 -pedantic singlefile.c`)?

Comment: What is your architecture, operating system, and verison of GCC?  Could you try removing unneeded arguments to the compiler and simplify your code to a single file and post the whole thing here so others can reproduce the problem?  (I tried to reproduce it and got the expected output.)  Also, show the commands that compile the full program, right now you are just compiling main.o but you aren't showing how you produced the final executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `-Wall` argument to the compiler.  With that you'd see a message like:

```
main.c:3:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘wtf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

which sort-of tells you the problem -- if you don't declare a function in a compilation unit before you try to call it, the compiler will assume that it returns `int` -- and in this case it looks like an `int` return value happens to be stored in the same place (probably some specific integer register) as the first argument.  So insetad of getting the return value the function actually trieds to return (probably in a floating-point register), it converts that `int` to float as you see.

Comment: but I declared it in test.h as "float wtf(int c);"

I did use -Wno-implicit-function-declaration, so you're right there comes the warning, but I dont see what I can do about it

Comment: Did you include test.h near the top of main.c?  I suggest simplifying your code so it fits in a single file and posting the full code.

Comment: declaring it in `test.h` does no good unless you also `#include "test.h"` in `main.c` -- you need the declaration to visible *in* the compilation unit before you call it.

Comment: ok that was the issue, I added all missing .h files and now it's working.

the problem with the c99 compiler is that it does not report errors when not finding a function

Comment: @ChrisDodd : Will using an `extern float wtf(int)` help if he doesn't include `test.h` in `main.c`?

Comment: only one thing though, usleep keeps giving me the error although I already added <unistd.h>, strange, I checked again, from the reference, it should be that one

Comment: @sjsam: Yes -- there just needs to be a declaration for `wtf` in the compilation unit.  Doesn't matter whether it comes from an included .h file or is directly in the file.

Comment: no it's already solved, the issue with usleep was that I had to use -std=gnu99 on compilation apparently

Comment: @user3455897 : My question was just out of curiosity. Your problem might have been solved following comment#3

Comment: @user3455897:  It's not a "problem" of the c99 compiler, it's a "feature" of the c99 language specification -- functions can be implicitly defined.  If you don't like it, you should probably be using some other, safer language than C.